# WiFi Won't Stay Connected on one PC

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

My desktop PC absolutely refuses to stay connected to my home WiFi. When it does connect to the router it almost always says "Connected, no Internet". After a few minutes it will typically disconnect on it's own. If it does manage to reach the outside world it does so at absolutely abysmal speeds. Meanwhile my laptop and Android can sit right next to it on the same desk and both have a near perfect connection and get 65Mbps down and 10 up. My desktop gets 0.07Mbps down, and 2 up.

I have tried every command I can think of. Flushdns, renew ip, etc. I turned off delivery optimization, everything is fully up to date, reinstalled drivers multiple times, rebooted the router, etc. I even "reinstalled" by downloading the ISO and running setup from within Windows. I was thinking of partitioning the boot drive just to see if it works at all with a clean install or not.

I read that the network card itself can have issues (Intel AX200) so I replaced it with the exact same card my laptop is using (Killer 1535) and while the connection seems more stable now it is still unable to use the internet. With the Ax200 the link transmit speed jumped around at random but usually settled around 24/130, it also jumped channels and between 2.4/5GHz a lot. With the Killer 1535 it sits at a consistent 866/866 and stays on channel 44 at 5GHz.

Looking at the Netsh wlanreport shows a number of errors after a fresh reboot and only trying to connect for about 10 minutes:

1. The network is disconnected by the driver. 7 counts.
2. The network is disconnected due to a policy disabling auto connect on this interface. 6 counts.
3. The network is disconnected due to a temporary-disconnect request. 5 counts.

I feel like I am at my wits end with this. I have tried everything I can possibly think of.

Edit: An old USB WiFi adapter (Belkin) I had laying around does work just fine, it's slow because it's old but it does work and connect without a problem. The Killer Wireless card is using the latest driver from Qualcomm, 12.0.0.1016 and I am on Windows 10 22H2 (19045.2788).

Edit 2: The belkin adapter just got disconnected randomly too.

Comment: have you tried [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/random-ethernet-and-wifi-disconnect/d5ba89d2-7cb6-41a8-a476-f0807a9e6c6f)

Comment: Try a USB wireless card. This will help determining if the existing card is not good.

Comment: Which Windows version and what driver are you using for the Killer card?

Comment: According to the results of your latest test with the old Belkin dongle we can hypothesize either 1) There's significant interference likely due to the position of the desktop, 2) some serious issue with your OS or 3) a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

facing the very same issue and found this from google
So afaik, we have two possibilities:

1. a NCI bug, only for W10
2. WCM - Minimize connection ↓

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/mobilebroadband/understanding-and-configuring-windows-connection-manager

If you've managed to solve this problem, I'm also curious about the solution/any workaround, cheers